# JQuery Calender Default Week Start From Mon

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, calendar

This is the default jQuery calender week start from Sun to Sat but I want default Mon to Sat. I am using jQuery Calender.

[image]

Comment: You should customize your code check the official documentation  of fullclendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `firstDay` parameter with 1 when you did initialize the calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({              
    firstDay: 1 
});
```

Also you can start from other days serially like Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc. Complete example,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
    firstDay: 1 
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Hopefully, this link will help you better [FullCalendar - firstDay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay)